How to access 2 roles at a time in snowflake
H All,
I'm encountering an issue with performing joins across tables that belong to different roles in our Snowflake environment.
Here's the scenario:
We have two roles: role_1, which has access to TableA, and role_2, which has access to TableB.
We've assigned both role_1 and role_2 to a user.
Now, the user needs to perform a join operation between TableA and TableB. However, due to the limitations of only being able to access one role at a time, they're encountering an error.

You could use the secondary roles. This helps you use the privileges available in two different roles within the same session through a single role.
USE SECONDARY ROLES { ALL }

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/use-secondary-roles
